# number of indices exceeds the number of dimensions of the indexed array vb

Tags: vb.net, recursion, binary-search

In **sub main** on the line where I'm calling my function I'm getting an error that I don't know how to fix:

> number of indices exceeds the number of dimensions of the indexed array

```
Module Module1
    Sub main()
        Dim names() As String = {"heimdall", "hella", "loki", "thor", "tyr", "odin"} 'list in order
        Dim last As Integer = names.Length - 1
        Dim first As Integer = 0
        Dim player As String = "thor"

        search(names(), last, first, player)

    End Sub

    Function search(ByVal names() As String, ByVal last As Integer, ByVal first As Integer, ByVal player As String)
        Dim midpoint As Integer = (first + last) \ 2
        Dim found As Boolean = False

        While found = False
            If last < first Then
                Return -1
            End If

            If names(midpoint) > player Then
                Return search(names, last, first, midpoint)
                found = True
            Else
                Return midpoint
                found = True
            End If
        End While


        Return midpoint 'automatically does this when found = true

    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: If you turn on Option Strict you will discover that your Function requires a data type. Also when you call your function recursively in the second Return statement you are passing the wrong data type with midpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parenthesis at the end of `names()` when passing it to the `search` method. You only need these when declaring the array.

```
search(names, last, first, player)
```